# How to remove duplicate text files with different names from a directory using diff?

Tags: bash, diff

I have a directory of some text files. These files may not have unique content. I want to keep only unique files and delete others.

I tried the following:

```
diff -sr directory/ copy-of-directory/
```

which returns:
Files directory/1.txt and copy-of-directory/1.txt are identical
Files directory/2.txt and copy-of-directory/2.txt are identical
Files directory/3.txt and copy-of-directory/3.txt are identical ...

but why does it not say (I confirmed that 1.txt and 2.txt do differ)
Files directory/1.txt and copy-of-directory/2.txt differ

Comment: Check here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192701/how-to-remove-duplicate-files-using-bash

Comment: @dmitryro  
<fdupes -rqdN directory >
does the job, but I'm still interested in knowing what am I doing wrong with diff

Comment: @rahuL `diff` only compares files with identical names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
find directory -type f | while read f1; do
  find copy-of-directory -type f | while read f2; do
    diff -s "$f1" "$f2" || rm -f "$f2"
  done
done
```